# rank function giving output in float and incremented by 3

Tags: pandas, rank

Please help me to get this desired output of one another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901248/convert-dataframe-columns-value-into-digital-number) by `rank` function. I tried like this `df.domain.rank(ascending=0)` but getting output in float and incremented by 3.

```
Input..
             type  domain
            0    1     yahoo.com
            1    1     google.com
            2    0     google.com
            3    0     aa.com
            4    0     google.com
            5    0     aa.com
            6    1     abc.com
            7    1     msn.com
            8    1     abc.com
            9    1     abc.com

    Expected output
          type  domain
        0    1     1
        1    1     2
        2    0     2
        3    0     3
        4    0     2
        5    0     3
        6    1     4
        7    1     5
        8    1     4
        9    1     4

My Attempt using rank function

   >>> df.domain.rank(ascending=0)

            0    1.0
            1    4.0
            2    4.0
            3    9.5
            4    4.0
            5    9.5
            6    7.0
            7    2.0
            8    7.0
            9    7.0
```

Comment: Also, some input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: I was trying to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901248/convert-dataframe-columns-value-into-digital-number using rank function.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i have updated my thread. There you can see i am getting result in float and incremented by 3.

Comment: Okay, so why are you using rank when you know it is giving you a different result from what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use method='dense':

```
df.domain.rank(method='dense')
```

Output:

```
0    5.0
1    3.0
2    3.0
3    1.0
4    3.0
5    1.0
6    2.0
7    4.0
8    2.0
9    2.0
Name: domain, dtype: float64
```

Or ascending = False,

```
df.domain.rank(method='dense', ascending=False)
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    3.0
2    3.0
3    5.0
4    3.0
5    5.0
6    4.0
7    2.0
8    4.0
9    4.0
Name: domain, dtype: float64
```